# Include files in JSF dynamically from enum?

Tags: jsf, enums, include, switch-statement, facelets

I want to swtich between a Type, which is set as enum in my Bean to dynamically include .xhtml files.

I have my Type of the object Device:

```
public static enum Type {
    Android, iOS, WP7, Windows, Blackberry;
}
```

And here I want to dynamically include different .xhtml files:

```
<ui:include src="./preview/WelcomePreviewAndroid.xhtml" />
<ui:include src="./preview/WelcomePreviewiOS.xhtml" />
<ui:include src="./preview/WelcomePreviewBlackberry.xhtml" />
```

This should depend on which Type is set in the Device:

```
#{skinningBean.currentDevice.type}
```

How can I implement the switch statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the rendered attribute you can set whether an item should be displayed or not.
Because the  does not contain any rendered attribute, you will have to surround it by another div e.g.:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{skinningBean.currentDevice.type == 'android'}">
    <ui:include src="./preview/WelcomePreviewAndroid.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: No there is no rendered option :( That would have beed too nice

Comment: Okay i fixed it by just surrounding it with an h:panelGroup, which has an rendered attribute. Please update your answer and I'll accept it :)